# Can I upgrade a wubi 10.04 install using a 11.04 install image

Tags: 10.04, 11.04, upgrade, wubi

I want to eventually update 10.04 to 11.04 on several computers using a USB.  I would like to try it first on a non-essential computer, but the most likely candidate is a test box I run a wubi install on.

Should this work?

Do I boot from the USB like I normally would, or is there another procedure?

Should this emulate the results I would expect when upgrading a normal install?

Comment: When updating you either have to go from LTS to LTS or do every release upgrade in between. So in other words, you'll first have to upgrade your installs to 10.10, then upgrade to 11.04.

Comment: Ward, this is an honest personal question, why did you comment and not answer? If this is the case, it (the answer) should have the chance to pull in a few up votes and maybe get accepted?  This happens fairly often and I never really understand why.

Comment: I didn't feel like it completely answered your question, the main focus of your question was about Wubi where I don't really have a clue about.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate that, I just always feel that information this useful, though it may not get accepted, should be more prominent and gain the votes it deserves, since starting at 8.10, I had never noticed that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only upgrade a **Wubi** install while booted into that install, so either using update manager, or from the alternate desktop CD image (cdromupgrade).

You cannot do it from Windows or by booting an Ubuntu CD/USB.

You can only upgrade to 11.04 from 10.10 - so you'd first need to upgrade from 10.04 to 10.10, but note that there are some problems with the wubi upgrade to 10.10 ([bug 653134](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/653134) and [bug 610898](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/610898)). These have been fixed for 11.04, but until the fix is backported to 10.10 you will likely suffer booting problems. You can find a solution for these problems here: [Wubi megathread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1639198)

With any upgrade I recommend backing up beforehand. With Wubi you can just copy the virtual disks (usually just the root.disk) in Windows beforehand. It's a good idea to copy C:\wubildr as well.

Comment: Great links, I often use Wubi on a short term basis (weeks or months) on work computers and these will definitely come in handy.